# How to fail e2e Angular Protractor/Jasmine tests using expect()?

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor, e2e-testing

How can I fail Angular e2e tests using Protractor/Jasmine using expect?

I have something like this:

```
it(`should compare values`, async (done) => {
    try {

        const newValue: number = await pageObject.getValue();

        expect(newValue).
            withContext(`Number should increase. Is: ${newValue}, was ${oldValue}`).
            toBeGreaterThan(oldValue);

    } catch (err) {
        await testRun.fail(err);
    }
    done();
});
```

where `oldValue` is defined in one of previous steps (declared before first it). Unfortunately at this moment, even if both values are equal (e.g. 1000), there is even no message about fail or something like this.

Doing this by something like this:

```
if (newValue <= oldValue || (isNaN(newValue) && isNaN(oldValue))) {
    throw new Error(`Number should increase. Is: ${newValue}, was ${oldValue}`);
}
```

looks like working, but I don't think that it is a good way of solving such testing.

I'm using Protractor 6.0.0 and Jasmine 3.5.0.

Comment: When you say there is no message about fail, can you include what you are seeing?

Comment: @DublinDev To be honest - I don't see any message that would suggest that there is a fail or something like this - no message provided through `withContext` or any other, just like  1000 is greater 1000. When I use `throw new Error()` then I can see something like "Test is failing now due to".

I'm expecting sth like this:
`Test e2e-001, e2e-001-20200226_18205 is failing now due to: Number should increase. Is: 1021, was 1021` produced by testRun, but instead catch is not reached and no any message, as mentioned before.

Unfortunately, I cannot include exact output.

Comment: One more thing - maybe I'm somehow wrong, as I can see this in reports generated by protractor beautiful reporter, but I don't see them in console of VSC, what I expected that will be shown.

Comment: try using the undocumented second arguement many jasmine matchers accept `expect(newValue).toBeGreaterThan(oldValue),`Number should increase. Is: ${newValue}, was ${oldValue}`;`. This won't explain why `withContext` is not working however

Comment: Apolgies, the formatting got messed up in that comment `expect(newValue).toBeGreaterThan(oldValue, \`Number should increase. Is: ${newValue}, was ${oldValue});\`);`

Answer (score 0):

```
expect (newValue >= oldValue ).toBe(true);
```